# Sails, Angular (SinglePageApplication): robust authentication and CRUD. How to?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, crud, single-page-application, sails.js

I've read several pages and pages on the subject, but all the material is fragmentary and has not led me to any conclusion. So I'm turning to this wonderful problem-solver site.

The title is quite explanatory: how can I do this?

- **For authentication**: Passport.js? It is robust and secure enough? And how to configure only the policies of Sails with Angular?

I need a Angular + Sails complete, even for the login and registration (no refresh of the page!).

- **For the CRUD**: I need to perform simple arithmetic calculations of average prices for some products and display to each user, so simple CRUD operations. Do you have some advice for this?

Comment: Alas, you're not giving the wonderful problem-solvers a problem to solve.  You might have better luck with this kind of question on the [Sails.js Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sailsjs); it's too broad and opinion-based for StackOverflow.  SO is intended more for when you have decided on a course of action and have specific coding questions / problems.

Comment: For example like this problem to solve: how to do robust and secure authentication in Angular over Sails?

Comment: Sorry, I meant specific coding problems, ideally where you can post example code.

Comment: Scott, can you help us with solid authentication in Angular using Sails's policies? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding CRUD, Have you tried angular-sails-bind? (https://github.com/diegopamio/angular-sails-bind). I made it for my own project and then decided to put it as a separated library so everybody could benefit and I could have my first experience developing a bower package.

I hope it could help you.

BTW: it works with sails 0.10 (as some things, like topic names had changed since 0.9). If you need to make it work with 0.9, just let me know and I'll happy to help.

Comment: Btw, I'm using sails-generate-auth (which generates passportjs boilerplate that integrated perfectly with sailsjs) and I'm pretty happy with it. You can check out how I used the code in GitHub (diegopamio/darasa)